# Chart created with chart JS scrolls and does not fit into the screen

Tags: css, chart.js

I am new to chartJS and was including a bar chart in one of the angular project,
Requirement: The container holding chart should completely fit into the screen immediately below the header and should not scroll, I don't want to hard code any pixels by setting width and height to the canvas tag as I will be making it responsive in future to smaller devices as well.

Approach :So I gave a height to the container div of 600px(I will set diff heights with @media quires for smaller devices in future) and the chart fits perfectly, but there is a scroll bar appearing with a light scroll happening , how do I fit it to the container without any scroll?

Can somebody help me out as to why is my card which holds the chart scrolls?

Solution tried:
I've made maintianaspect ratio : false, and responsiveness true: still the container holding the chart scrolls

Attaching a screenshot with the scroll bar[The highlighted area is the scroll bar and the the card which holds the chart is also scrolling slightly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u8TA.png)

Thanks to any solutions in advance

I'm also pasting my ts ,scss , html code here

````
html

<div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="logo">
            
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="seacrh here">
            <label for="serach"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
        <div class="user">
            <img src="" alt="no Image available">
        </div>
    </div>
   
   
    <div class="main">
       
        <div class="charts">
            <div class="chart">
              
            <div style="position: relative;height:600px">
            <canvas  class="canvasHeight" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData"
                         [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins" [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [type]="barChartType">
            </canvas>
           </div>
            </div>
           

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

scss

.user{
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}

.user img{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%; //fits the parent area only since position is absolute
    height:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.topbar{
 position: fixed;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
 width:100%;
 height:60px; // use this for top bar calculations
 padding:0 20px;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr 0.4fr 1fr;
 align-items: center;
 z-index: 1;
}


   
.logo h2{
    color: #299B63;
}

.search{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    justify-self: center;
}

.search input{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.search i{
    position: absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:15px;
    cursor: pointer;  
}


 //main section
 .main{
     border:2px solid blue;
     position: absolute;
     top:60px;
     width:100%;
     min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);// subtract the header width
     background: #f5f5f5;
 }

 .cards{
     width:100%;
     padding:35px 20px;
     display: grid;
     width:100%;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
     grid-gap: 20px;
 }

 .cards .card{
     padding: 20px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 10px;
     box-shadow: 0 7px 25px 0 rgbs(0,0,0,0.08);
 }

 .number{
     font-size: 35px;
     font-weight: 500;
     color: #299B63;
 }

 .card-name{
     color: #888;
     font-weight: 600;
 }

 .icon-box i{
     font-size: 600;
     color: #299B63;
 }

 //charts css

 .charts{
     display: grid;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
     grid-gap: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 20px;
     padding-top: 23px;
 }

 .chart{
     background: #fff;
     padding: 20px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     box-shadow: 0 7px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid green;
          
 }


ts

```import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataset } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BarChartComponent  {
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
  
};
public barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', 
'2011', '2012'];
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartPlugins = [];

public barChartData: ChartDataset[] = [
{ data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
{ data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
];


}```
````